# Fallback for 404 page in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm creating a "userdir" configuration, where the webserver serves files inside each user's ~/www directory.

I have the following configuration snippet:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:433;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name ~^(?<user>\w+)\.example\.com$;

    root /var/www/userdir;
    index index.html;
    error_page 404 = @not_found;
    add_header X-User $user;

    location / {
        root /home/$user/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location @not_found {
        if (-f /home/$user/www/404.html)
        {
            root /home/$user/www;
        }

        try_files /404.html =500;
    }
}
```

When a non-existing file is requested, the `@not_found` named location is entered. It first checks whether the user has a custom 404 page, and if (s)he has, it sets the document root to the user's directory before trying to serve 404.html.

However, the result of the configuration block is that if 404.html exists in the user dir, the generic nginx 404 page is returned; if not, /var/www/userdir/404.html is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if` within a `location` block is counter intuitive, as [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) illustrates. Also, using `error_page` with a named location, changes the response code from 404 to 200, which may not be desirable.

You can use your test to set a variable at the top of the `server` block, which can then be used to set the location of the error page file.

For example:

```
set $ERROR_ROOT "/var/www/userdir";
if (-f /home/$user/www/404.html) {
    set $ERROR_ROOT "/home/$user/www";
}

error_page 404 /404.html;

location / {
    root /home/$user/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location = /404.html {
    root $ERROR_ROOT;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why my solution doesn't work, even after reading the article you linked and more. Thank you for providing a working solution.

Comment: Is there an equal character in the second location ?

Comment: @Stephane see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for the syntax of the `location` directive.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
location / {
    root /home/$user/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

You may need to remove the "error_page 404 = @not_found;".